# Calculate 50th & 75th Percentile in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, percentile

I would like to calculate 25th & 50th Percentile Value from the multiple records I have from one database table, not just percentile rank. Have tried many methods found online but still could not solve this problem..

A sample of how the SQL table looks like:

```
|Product|Quantity|
+ ----------------+
| Apple |  30    | 
| Apple |  29    |
| Apple |  43    |
| Apple |  10    |
| Kiwi  |  20    |
|Durian |   5    |
|Durian |  10    |
|Durian |  20    |
|Durian |  15    |
```

What I want to do is to get the value of 25th & 50th Percentile ranking of each Product grouping.

The output would look something like this(based on sample example above):

```
|Product|25thPercentile(Value)|50Percentile(Value)|
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Apple |        10           |        29.5       |
| Kiwi  |        20           |         20        |
|Durian |         5           |         12.5      |
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried the NTILE function to calculate those Percentile values but it doesn't work. :( The PERCENTILE_CONT() function is only available in SQL Server 2012. Do you know how can I work this out?

Comment: Short research with "sql server percentile" brought me here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/79688/5089204. Think you'll find your solution there... Please try some research first before you ask the next time, thx!

Comment: thanks for the link! i have tried it before but it does not work.. The below is a sample of my code.